# android retrieve contact image thumbnail

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I have to display thumbnails of contacts of my contacts in a listview which has a custom cursor adapter implementation. First I did it using asynctask and in the doInBackground method, I used the following snippet to get the bitmap of thumbnail.

```
Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                        Long.parseLong(params[0]));
InputStream input = ContactsContract.Contacts
                        .openContactPhotoInputStream(
                                mContext.getContentResolver(), uri);
    if (input != null) {
       mThumb = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
    } else {
          mThumb = defaultPhoto;
}
```

It gives me correct bitmap.

Later, I came to know about [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader). I implemented a custom BaseImageDownlaoder as in the following snippet. `public class ContactImageDownloader extends BaseImageDownloader{

```
private static final String SCHEME_CONTACT_IMAGE = "content";
private static final String DB_URI_PREFIX = SCHEME_CONTACT_IMAGE + "://";
private Context mContext;

public ContactImageDownloader(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
protected InputStream getStreamFromOtherSource(String imageUri, Object extra) throws IOException {
    if (imageUri.startsWith(DB_URI_PREFIX)) {
        
        InputStream input = ContactsContract.Contacts
                .openContactPhotoInputStream(
                        mContext.getContentResolver(), Uri.parse(imageUri));
        
        ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        
        if (input!=null) {
            IoUtils.copyStream(input, output);
        } else {
  //default image
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.wiresimage);
            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, BUFFER_SIZE, output);
        }

        byte[] imageData = output.toByteArray();
        input.close();
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(imageData);
    } else {
        return super.getStreamFromOtherSource(imageUri, extra);
    }
}`
}
```

But it doesn't retrieve the image. In the log, it shows `java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist; URI: content://com.android.contacts/contacts/567, calling user: com.c` 
So, now in order to verify my implementation (to check if my custom BaseImageDownloader is wrong), I put the snippet I used in asynctask's doInBackground method to bindView method of cursor adapter. But still, the InputStream is null i.e. FileNotFoundException. But everything works right in Asynctask. Please help. Thanks!